# How to set a reference/lookup field through Price Action in SF CPQ?

Tags: lookup, cpq, pricerule

I am working on a Price Rule which has one of the action to update lookup fields on Quote Line.

To elaborate we have From and To (reference to Location custom object) on Line Group and we'd like to copy these on Quote Lines as well.

The price action copies the Id correctly but CPQ doesn't represent the Location Name it just shows the Id which isn't useful .  Here is an example. From has the Location Name correctly(same logic done through QCP) and To has just Location Id(done through Price Rule).

[image]

Is this an expected behavior or i'm doing something wrong?

If yes does that imply that Price Rules has a major restriction while copying over to reference fields like one shown above?

What should be the workaround in this case? Our aim is to do this through Price Rule and not QCP due to certain reasons.

-Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure both fields are lookups? Can you provide a screen shot of the field definitions?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried replicating your issue on Price Action. Setting up value as the Lookup Id as you mentioned.

[image: Price Action]

Then via Quote > Edit Lines, I am able to get it populated with the Contact.Name (as per my lookup(Contact)). So no issues seen.

Maybe you need to upgrade your CPQ installed package (there definitely has been a new version upgrade)? My version number is 240.5